# SharePoint Online folder with "#" not found

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I am using the SharePoint Online CSOM library (16.1.8316.1200) to retrieve info about a SharePoint Online folder using the web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl. This works great except for when the folder contains a "#" character. In that case, a ServerException 'File Not Found' is returned. I have tried encoding the "#" character as "%23" but that did not work either. Any ideas of what I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a folder name containing special characters such as `#` and `%` using the new `GetFolderByServerRelativePath` method.

You can use the below snippet:

```
string folderName = "Test#123";

var folder = clientContext.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativePath(ResourcePath.FromDecodedUrl($"/sites/TestSite/Documents{folderName}"));
clientContext.Load(folder);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

Console.Write(folder.Name);
```

Reference - [Web.GetFolderByServerRelativePath method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/mt807019(v%3Doffice.15))

Answer (score 1):

Reproduced, here is my test workaround.

```
var folders = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/Developer/MyDoc4/SubFolder").Folders;                
                context.Load(folders, fs => fs.Where(f => f.ServerRelativeUrl == "/sites/Developer/MyDoc4/SubFolder/T#T")); ;
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach (var _F in folders)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(_F.Name);
                }
```