# SharePoint REST request for 'breakroleinheritance' with special character in folder name

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-permissions, break-inheritance

I am making a REST request to SharePoint for breaking the role inheritance for a folder.

It's working fine when a folder does not have any special character in it's name.

But when I add special charter(s) to a folder name, my request for `breakroleinheritance` is failing and I am getting below error from the web service.

> "error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ResourceNotFoundException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Cannot find resource for the request SP.RequestContext.current/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/foldertop/subfolder/2020/Oklahoma/20-4152 test permission for parts2020%23%40%26')/ListItemAllFields/."}}}

For example:
**20-4152 test permission for parts2020#@&** this is my folder name and after doing URL ending it becomes **20-4152%20test%20permission%20for%20parts2020%23%40%26**.

Below is the full endpoint along with relative URL for my folder,
Please know that if I remove the special characters `#@&` then same request is working fine.

```
https://mysharepoint.sharepoint.com/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/foldertop/subfolder/2020/Oklahoma/20-4152%20test%20permission%20for%20 parts2020%23%40%26')/ListItemAllFields/breakroleinheritance(true)
```

Does this mean that the SharePoint REST API request does not support special characters?

Comment: try using `encodeURIComponent` https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/167125/issue-with-symbol-in-rest-api

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has made some changes to support some of the old special characters that used to be restricted.

[Supporting % and # in files and folders with the ResourcePath API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/supporting-and-in-file-and-folder-with-the-resourcepath-api)

So instead of using `GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl` you need to use `GetFolderByServerRelativePath`.

This question/answer is about the same problem (the hash #): [SharePoint Online folder with "#" not found](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/254299/sharepoint-online-folder-with-not-found)

Comment: I just tried bt removing slash before library name, and did encoding as you have mentioned which makes the endpoint like this.                        endpoint=>https://midwestmach.sharepoint.com/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('topfolder%2Fsubfolder%2F2020%2FOklahoma%2Ftest%20permission%20for%20parts2020%23%40%26')/ListItemAllFields/breakroleinheritance(true)           But I am still getting the same error

Comment: here is the error : Cannot find resource for the request SP.RequestContext.current/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('topfolder/subfolder/2020/Oklahoma/20-4152 test permission for parts2020#@&')/ListItemAllFields/.

Comment: Did you encode the rest of the folder path and use the variable instead in your code?

Comment: Yes I did and it makes my url look like this => https://mysharepoint.sharepoint.com/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('topfolder%2Fsubfolder%2F2020%2FOklahoma%2Ftest%20permission%20for%20parts2020%23%40%26')/ListItemAllFields/breakroleinheritance(true)

Comment: My misstake, according to MS there should be a slash in the start. however i think you should write it as /breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=true, clearSubscopes=true) and not just (true).

Comment: Yes I  will do (copyRoleAssignments=true, clearSubscopes=true)  when i want to assign the role. but here i am making the request to break inheritance as given here https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/fc34aa/break-inheritance-and-add-role-permissions-using-rest-api-in/          which is working fine except the folder which has a special character in it